# AIX option O_NSHARE during open system call, not available on Centos 7

Tags: c, linux, aix

I am attempting to port code from AIX to Linux (Centos7 32bit). In doing so I have a snip of code that I cannot find like for like and would appreciate any advise. In the open system call I am trying to assure that no process has this file open and precludes subsequent opens. Please let me know if/how this functionality can be ported to Linux.

Below is a snip of code that work on AIX.

```
if( -1 != (fd = open(pidfname, O_RDWR|O_NSHARE|O_NDELAY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH)) ) {
```

Comment: If you just want to prevent concurrent access by multiple instances of the program, `flock` would probably be the closest thing.  Otherwise, I don't know if there are any "mandatory locks" available in Linux.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the reply, I'm aware of flock and lockf, however there are limitations even with those with respect to race conditions. I would like to "lock" the file before the file is opened/created.

Comment: Your concept of locking sounds strange. Even "before file is created"? That's roughly equivalent to "prevent a path name to be created"